# Why onClick of delete button ajax call is not working after the button is being appended into the div element?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, handlebars.js, prepend

On load page I am appending the comments via `AJAX` call and all the comments have been successfully posted. All the comments have their respective delete buttons with the common class and unique ids.
So `Onclick` of delete button I want to delete the respective comment but however its access is not coming into the `AJAX` call. I have tried with alert as well but its not working I don't know why.
What I am doing wrong?

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
    var AddtasksId = $('#submitBtn4comment').attr('data-taskId');
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/getComments",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        AddtasksId: AddtasksId
      },
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(response){
    $.each(response, function(key,comment) {
    appendToDom(comment);
         });
    }
    });
    
    });
    
    function appendToDom(data) {
        let lTag = document.createElement('li')
        lTag.classList.add('comment', 'mb-3')
    
        let markup = `
        <div class="card border-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>${data.username}</h5>
                <p style="background-color:#E8E8E8">${data.comment}</p>
                <div><h6>⏲️ ${data.commentDate}<span class="pull-right"></span></h6></div>
                <a href="/deleteComment" id="${data._id}" class="deleteComments">Delete Comment</a>
                <div id="line"><hr  style="" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
        lTag.innerHTML = markup
    
        $(".comment__box").prepend(lTag);
    }
    
    </script>
```

html div tags where it is appending:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <div class="typing text-success"></div> -->
        <ul class="comment__box commonText">
        </ul>


</div>
</div>
```

This is `AJAX` call for deleting the comment:
but on clicking the `<a>` button the access is not coming means `alert` doesn't popup.

```
$(".deleteComments").on("click", function() {

  alert("First alert");

    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    var AddtasksId = $('#submitBtn4comment').attr('data-taskId');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/deleteComment",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      AddtasksId: AddtasksId,
      id:id
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response){
    if(response.status == 200)
    window.location.reload();
  }
  });
})
```

Comment: Because you button is dynamically generated. Use `$(document).on("click",".deleteComments", function() {`

Comment: still need to place it in ajax callback

Comment: @Nik dont understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Biku `$(".deleteComments")` will only returns `[HTML Elements]` after calling `appendToDom`. So you must call it after the buttons get appended into `document.body`

Comment: @Nik that would not be needed, all he need is to change the click function so it handles event delegation.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Let me try and then will get back to you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks! This worked smoothly. :) @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event is not triggered because the element does not exist when the event is defined.

you can solve that this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteComments", function() {
```

Comment: still need to place it in ajax callback

Comment: @Nik Why? if you set the event on document, it works for dynamically added elements.